# Setting Latitude and Longitude in Google Maps - undefined results

Tags: php, json, google-maps

Currently using downloadURL() on home.php that downloads an xml.php file.  Creates xml doc from database to display markers on map.  Worked fine earlier, but now I'm receiving errors around geoCode/lat/long.  Any advice? FireFox error: undefined offset [0] via results.

```
<?php    
 include 'connect.php';
 if(isset($_SESSION['user_name']))
 {
     header('Location: home.php');
 }
     $query = "SELECT `acc_id`,`acc_name`,`acc_address`,acc_zip FROM `account_acc` ";
     $result = mysqli_query($connection,$query) or die(mysql_error());

     $doc = new DomDocument('1.0');
     $node = $doc->createElement("markers");
     $parnode = $doc->appendChild($node);

     header('Content-type: text/xml');

     while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
     {
       $node = $doc->createElement("marker");
       $newnode = $parnode->appendChild($node);

        $address = $row['acc_zip'];
        $prepAddr = str_replace(' ','+',$address);
                 $geocode=file_get_contents('https://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?key=API&address='.$prepAddr);
        $output= json_decode($geocode);
        $lat = $output->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
        $long = $output->results[0]->geometry->location->lng;

        $newnode->setAttribute("name", $row['acc_name']);
        $newnode->setAttribute("accid", $row['acc_id']);
        $newnode->setAttribute("address", $row['acc_address']);
        $newnode->setAttribute("zip", $row['acc_zip']);
        $newnode->setAttribute("lat", $lat);
        $newnode->setAttribute("long", $long);

       }

       print $doc->saveXML();
```

?>

Answer (score 0):

There aren't lat/lng properties of location, they are functions (lat()/lng()).

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you are getting the error `undefined offset [0]` since the provided address (`$address` variable) could not be determined and the response contains empty `results`. For that case [Google Maps Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#StatusCodes) provides `Status Codes`:

> - "OK" indicates that no errors occurred; the address was successfully    parsed and at least one geocode was returned.
> - "ZERO_RESULTS" indicates that the geocode was successful but returned    no results. This may occur if the geocoder was passed a
>     non-existent    address.
> - "OVER_QUERY_LIMIT" indicates that you are over your quota.
> - "REQUEST_DENIED" indicates that your request was denied.
> - "INVALID_REQUEST" generally indicates that the query (address,    components or latlng) is missing.
> - "UNKNOWN_ERROR" indicates that the request could not be processed due    to a server error. The request may succeed if you try again.

that you could utilize to determine whether address has been resolved.

**Example**

```
$geocode = file_get_contents('https://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=' . $prepAddr);
$output = json_decode($geocode);
if($output->status == "OK"){

    $lat = $output->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
    $long = $output->results[0]->geometry->location->lng;

    //the remaining code goes here...
}
```